# Curly Calligraphic capital A?

Tags: math-mode, symbols, mtpro

I'm writing my final work of the career, but I can't find how to write this symbol.

[image]

It's like a weird "a" before (*θ*, *ϕ*).

Thank you so much!

Comment: Have a look at [“How to look up a symbol?”](//tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14) for ideas how you can easily find a particular symbol.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! It's not a weird symbol: it's an “A” in a calligraphic font. Use `\mathcal{A}` and you'll be OK even if the shape is different.

Comment: @egreg --- but it's a lower case 'a' ...

Comment: @IanThompson I don't think so; to me it's an uppercase script A in a smaller font.

Comment: It would be much more helpful to your career if you skip such arcane notation in my humble opinion.

Comment: Looks also a little like `\mathcal{a}` from [mtpro2](http://www.pctex.com/mtpro2.html), but that's a commercial font. (i.e. not free)

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/JkJwK7x.gif

Comment: @Davislor No. Looking for a curly script capital A is a duplicate of this question. Look at the time of asking.

Comment: @JouleV I should just call it a night. I'm making a lot of silly mistakes today.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The closest I could find is `TypoUprightBT`:

```
    \documentclass[12pt]{article}
    \usepackage{amsmath} 
    \usepackage{fontspec}
    \pagestyle{empty}
    \newfontfamily{\uprightcal}{TypoUpright BT}

    \begin{document}%

    \[ \text{\uprightcal{A}}\mkern1mu(\theta, \phi) \]

    \end{document}
```

[image: Example of the font]

Comment: In `unicode-math`, you can either `\setmathfont[range=cal]{TypoUpright BT}` and use it as `\mathcal{A}` or `\setmathfontface\uprightcal{TypoUpright BT}` and use `\uprightcal{A}` (which no longer requires `\text`).

Answer (score 5):

The A of your image might seem the same of full [mt2pro](https://ctan.org/pkg/mtp2lite) package:

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book} 
\usepackage[mtpccal]{mtpro2}
\begin{document}
\[\mathcal{A}(\theta,\phi)\]
\end{document}
```

I think the letter has been retouched to get bold with an external program that uses TrueType fonts. In the image you can see that in the character map there is the bold font (MT2MCS):

[image]

Comment: From where you got `mtpro2`?

Comment: @Sigur From the guide `https://pctex.com/files/managed/1/1b/mtpro2Abbrev.pdf` pag. 7.