# Looking for a curly script capital A

Tags: fonts, symbols

A math book I'm studying uses a symbol and I'd like to be able to reproduce it.  I used detexify to search for it, but was unsuccessful. Most likely it is the letter 'a' in some font I'm not familiar with.

Here's a zoomed in image of the symbol:

[image]

Here it is in context:

[image]

Comment: This looks like an 'old-fashioned' German letter a, as it was used in older text books about linear algebra in Germany here

Comment: This sounds plausible.  The book is Hoffman and Kunze's Linear Algebra, which was originally published in 1971.

Comment: You find it in the MathTime Pro 2 Curly script, commercial. [This picture (click)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4p2lr.png) is taken from the documentation of `mathalfa`.

Comment: Yes, mathtime pro 2 curly looks like it's exactly it.  Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does anyone know how to write this symbol?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/378460/does-anyone-know-how-to-write-this-symbol)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you appear to be using a bitmapped font from last century that costs money, here’s a modern equivalent.  You can use whatever other TrueType or OpenType font looks better to you, but this version will automatically scale the font you select to the same height.  You might want to choose it as `\mathscr` instead, or use `\mscript` for compatibility with the MathTime Pro package.

```
\documentclass[varwidth, preview]{standalone}
\usepackage{unicode-math}

\defaultfontfeatures{ Scale = MatchUppercase }
\setmathfontface\mathcscr{DobkinPlain.ttf}

\begin{document}
vector space \(\mathcscr{A}\) over \(\mathcal{F}\)
\end{document}
```

[image: Vector Space A over F]

The font I used is available [here](https://www.fontsquirrel.com/fonts/dobkin).

If you want to use the original symbol, I recommend loading `\usepackage[scr = mtc]{mathalfa}` with an appropriate `scrscaled =` factor to make the font the right size.

Answer (score 3):

The option of `mtpccal` for full [`mtpro2`](https://www.pctex.com/mtpro2.html) package (not free) has the font Math Curly alphabets:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book} 
\usepackage[mtpccal]{mtpro2}
\begin{document}
\[\mathcal{A}\]
\end{document}
```

The output it taken from the site at the link https://www.pctex.com/mtpro2.html:

[image]