# EuScript gives a strange error, even with included files

Tags: pdftex, styles

I wanted to use 
the curly S style, so that I wrote this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\DeclareMathAlphabet\EuScript{U}{eus}{m}{n}
\SetMathAlphabet\EuScript{bold}{U}{eus}{b}{n}

\begin{document}

\[ \mathcal{A} = \EuScript{A} \neq \CMcal{A} \]

\end{document}
```

but it yields the following error.

```
Command Line:   bibtex.exe "ideje7"
Startup Folder: C:\Users\hynek0\Desktop\TH0dipl

This is BibTeX, Version 0.99d (MiKTeX 2.9 64-bit)
The top-level auxiliary file: ideje7.aux
I found no \citation commands---while reading file ideje7.aux
I found no \bibdata command---while reading file ideje7.aux
I found no \bibstyle command---while reading file ideje7.aux
(There were 3 error messages)


Command Line:   pdflatex.exe --interaction=errorstopmode --synctex=-1 "C:\Users\hynek0\Desktop\TH0dipl\ideje7.tex"
Startup Folder: C:\Users\hynek0\Desktop\TH0dipl

This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.15 (MiKTeX 2.9 64-bit)
entering extended mode
(C:/Users/hynek0/Desktop/TH0dipl/ideje7.tex
LaTeX2e <2014/05/01>
Babel <3.9l> and hyphenation patterns for 68 languages loaded.
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexExe\tex\latex\base\article.cls
Document Class: article 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexExe\tex\latex\base\size10.clo))
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexExe\tex\latex\amsmath\amsmath.sty
For additional information on amsmath, use the `?' option.
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexExe\tex\latex\amsmath\amstext.sty
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexExe\tex\latex\amsmath\amsgen.sty))
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexExe\tex\latex\amsmath\amsbsy.sty)
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexExe\tex\latex\amsmath\amsopn.sty))
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexExe\tex\latex\amsfonts\amssymb.sty
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexExe\tex\latex\amsfonts\amsfonts.sty)) (ideje7.aux)
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexExe\tex\latex\amsfonts\umsa.fd)
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexExe\tex\latex\amsfonts\umsb.fd)
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexExe\tex\latex\amsfonts\ueus.fd)
! Undefined control sequence.
l.9 \[ \mathcal{A} = \EuScript{A} \neq \CMcal
                                             {A} \]
?
```

Any help/suggestions?

Comment: Where did you define `\CMcal`?

Comment: I've just copied a bunch of code from [here](http://www.maths.usyd.edu.au/u/SMS/texdoc/euscript.pdf) I'm a beginner.

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 1):

Euler Script is a good choice!  I love that font, and it goes very well with Hermann Zapf’s more famous typeface, Palatino.

### My Recommendation

I hope this answer doesn’t get too complicated.  What that document was trying to say is, `\usepackage{eucal}`, but it made the mistake of starting off with an advanced example of what not to do.

I use the modern toolchain, with either XeTeX or LuaTeX, when I can, and legacy 8-bit fonts only when I have to.  Looking at the link you provided, that’s demonstrating something not very useful: combining Euler Script and Computer Modern Symbol script in the same document.

If you actually do want to use two different script alphabets in the same document, they should be more visually different from each other.  My own practice is to define `\mathcal` as something that looks like the default calligraphic letters, and `\mathscr` as a second script alphabet in another style, usually a lightly-slanted cursive.

Both the alphabets from the example you give are available as the Mathematical Script range of OpenType math alphabets.  Latin Modern Math is a clone of Computer Modern, and should already be included in your TeX distribution.  AMS Euler is available in OTF as [Neo Euler](https://github.com/khaledhosny/euler-otf).  You can either install the font or copy it to the `fonts` subdirectory of your local texmf folder.

In practice, the template you’d use to get Euler Script as your `\mathcal` is something like this:

```
\usepackage{unicode-math}

\defaultfontfeatures{ Scale = MatchUppercase }
\setmathfont{Latin Modern Math} % Or your math font of choice.
\setmathfont[range = {cal, bfcal}]{Neo Euler}
```

Here’s how you would reproduce that exact sample with `unicode-math`.  (Don’t actually do this.)

```
\documentclass[varwidth, preview]{standalone}
\usepackage{unicode-math}

\defaultfontfeatures{ Scale = MatchUppercase }
\setmathfont{Latin Modern Math}
\setmathfont[range = {scr, bfscr}]{Neo Euler}

\begin{document}
\( \mathscr{A} = \mathscr{A} \neq \mathcal{A} \)
\end{document}
```

[image: OpenType font sample]

If you actually need two different script and calligraphic fonts in the same document, here’s an example that isn’t crazy:

```
\documentclass[varwidth, preview]{standalone}
\usepackage{unicode-math}

\defaultfontfeatures{ Scale = MatchUppercase }
\setmainfont[Scale = 1.0, Ligatures = Common]{TeX Gyre Pagella}
\setmathfont{Asana Math}
\setmathfont[range = {cal, bfcal}]{Neo Euler}
\setmathfont[range = {scr, bfscr}, StylisticSet = 1]{STIX Two Math}

\begin{document}
\[ \mathcal{A} = \mathcal{A} \neq \mathscr{A} \]
\end{document}
```

[image: Font sample]

I haven’t ever used `\mathscr` in a real paper, but if I did, that definition of it is visually distinct from `\mathcal` and not excessively slanted.  [But, you can load any font you want as a math alphabet.](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/470766/looking-for-a-curly-script-capital-a/470814#470814)

The `\setmathfont[range = {cal, bfcal}]` command loads the script and bold-script alphabets from any math font.  You could also load any decorative OpenType or TrueType font with `\setmathfont[range=cal]` or `\setmathfont[range=scr]`.

### Backward-Compatibility

If you need backward-compatibility with PDFTeX, I’d recommend you load your math alphabets with [`mathalfa`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/mathalfa/doc/mathalfa.pdf), which also has good font samples of all the alternatives, and `isomath`.

```
\documentclass[varwidth, preview]{standalone}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{textcomp} % Not actually needed here.
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % The default since 2018
\usepackage[ cal = cm,
             scr = euler
           ]{mathalfa}

\begin{document}
\( \mathscr{A} = \mathscr{A} \neq \mathcal{A} \)
\end{document}
```

[image: PDFTeX example]

However, the easiest way to use Euler Script is to `\usepackage{eucal}` to replace the `\mathcal` alphabet, or `\usepackage{euscript}` to add it as `\mathscr`.