# How to produce this variant of letter 'a'?

Tags: math-mode, letters

I would like to produce a variant of letter `a` as shown below

[image]

The source is [Shoenfield's *Mathematical Logic*](https://doi.org/10.1201/9780203749456) book (first occurrence in p18) and it is used to denote structures. It appears (to me) like a large calligraphic variant of lowercase `a`. I use `\cal A` instead, and I have also looked over some other alternatives (e.g. the `\frac` ones) but I would like to use that precise symbol in my notes if possible.

The results from [detexify](http://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html) were not really that useful in this case either:

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: see https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/470766/2388

Answer (score 2):

This symbol is available from the "curly" variant of the commercial `MTPro2` package. See the [MTPro2 package homepage](https://www.pctex.com/mtpro2.html) for more information.

[Disclaimer: I am in no way affiliated with `MTPro2`, but it is the only place I know that has the symbol]